# What is the relationship between universal-robot and Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the description, it seems both provide some sort of ROS driver for the UR robot.  `universal-robot` seems to contain additional moveit and gazebo resources, while `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` seem to contain a more fully fleshed out c++ ROS driver.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371237/what-is-the-relationship-between-universal-robot-and-universal_robots_ros_driver?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short:

- `universal_robot` hosts an old, community contributed and deprecated driver which will be removed
- `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` is the officially supported driver for all Universal Robots robots with CB3 controllers and newer

`universal_robot` also contains description packages and MoveIt configurations, and those will stay supported.

The `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` build instructions in the readme currently require you to clone a fork of `universal_robot`. That will change once things have been merged back into upstream.

See also [wiki/ur_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_driver), [ros-industrial/universal_robot#448](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/448) and [Deprecation of ur_modern_driver](https://discourse.ros.org/t/deprecation-of-ur-modern-driver/11629).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2